# TestNG Code running Without Error but html Output says Zero

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

My code is working without errors but when I run the testNG there is no pass or fail test run.

Can anyone please explain me why is it happen?

I've added the following libraries:

- JRE System Library
- Selenium-java 2.52.0-srcs.jar
- Selenium-java 2.52.0.jar
- TestNG

[Login Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lSGJ.png)

[TestNG report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EQgh.png)

Comment: Please, instead of posting a link to an image, update your question with the code developed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have not used testng tags..
In fact you have not used testng at all..

Please see the testng tutorial

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_overview.htm

Comment: can you specify, what should i use, and where i should use those tags, i'm  new to selenium and eclipse.